# Evaluating whether a surface apperance is light or dark for the case incident light is in normal direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, refraction, interference

The Question:

> The system in the figure is illuminated in the normal direction
> by wide  monochromotic light source in the first environment.
> Explain in detail the light and dark condition of the boundary surface
> seperating 1st and 2nd environment in the following conditions:
>
> (a)   n1 < n2 < n3
> (b)   n3 = n1 < n2

[image]

*What I confused here is:*

Incident light is said in normal direction so it's perpendiculer to the surface.
Hence light will continue as it comes in with no reflection no refraction, only velocity of light differs between environments.

if incident light had some incident angle then thin film approache is applicable.
If incident light were not monochromatic dispersion could be considered...

So my conclusion is, regardles of (a) and (b) we see nothing (dark!) for no reflection on any surfaces.

What I'm missing here?

Thank you all even readers of my post.

*Note that*,  n_i are refraction indicies (It is not  been clearly stated in the question but it's well known) do imply that all environments are transparent.

Comment: Have you never noticed your reflection in a window?

Comment: No, just the other side of window. The answer looks as if "light" but question does not state  if is there any object in the "other side"  to reflect the light back So I said "dark".The question had been asked at a university 3rd semester of  Physics division. So I 'm still thinking what I'm missing for the answer should not be so easy!

Answer (score 0):

The dark condition is that one that you shall find, that is under what circunstances the light do not enter in te 2nd enviroment with the restrictions a) and b) , one may be that  in de  $n_2$ all the light is absorbed, so in the 2th enviroment  will be no ligth and from the 1rs material you will see dark  (but this is more complicated because you need to work with Poyting vector and the refraction indices may be complex numbers), one simple attempt is that in the $n_3$   we have  $n_3=\frac{c}{v_3}$, so if there is no ligth in the second enviroment $v_3=0$ , this implies that $n_3=\infty$ so this fall in the restriction a). Other might be how is the distance $d$ for no light in the 2nd enviroment.